Text SMS with Special Character in Canada
I am trying to send Mobile optin SMS(double OptIn) for Canadian carrier for French and Spanish language along with English.
I am referring content block created in Content builder in Mobile optin OUTBOUND RESPONSE block and OUTBOUND CONFIRMATION block. However if the text is more than 160 characters it is delivered as 2 different SMS instead 1. But for US carrier it is sending as 1 SMS with the same settings
We tried using SMS Message block in content builder with CONCATE function and tried to refer the block in MobileOptin blocks using ContentBlockById but it throws an default error message from setup.
Is there a way to send or use SMS Message block with CONCATE function if text is more than 160 characters for CANADA region?
Also note if we use the French/Spanish special characters (é,á ,ó,í) in text, SMS are limited to 70 characters only(which is as per documents) and multiple SMS send happen and also the order is jumbled up but the same text works fine for US carrier

Looking at the documentation article below, if you're using non-Global System for Mobile Communications (GSM) characters in your message it will limit it to 70 characters for Canadian customers. Similarly, some factors, such as the sender code, the recipient’s carrier, or location, can prevent concatenation where the messages come through as multiple messages instead of a concatenated message. Also, are you using the Concat function instead of the Concate function, with emphasis on the e at the end of Concate. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_message_content_considerations.htm&type=5

Hi @MrTD, I am not using any Concatenation Ampscript function in my code block. I am simply referring my message in code snippet block in Mobile OptIn template. Yes, you are right it may be carrier n location constraints restricting text limitations
